# Google Speech To Text API in React Native

Tags: react-native, speech-to-text

I'm doing a project by React Native with following features
1. Users start recording audio
2. Stop recording audio
3. Save audio
4. Translate it to text (In my case translate to Vietnamese)

I'm done with 1,2,3. But I'm stuck at 4, I don't know how to use Google STT API with an audio file input, because it seems like just use STT as an intent.

Hope any ideas or solution related!

---

Here's my code:

```
requestAPI() {
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')({
  projectId: 'speech-to-text-175801',
  keyFilename: '/keyfile.json'
});

const RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'speech-to-text-175801';

// Instantiates a client
const speechClient = Speech({
  projectId: projectId,
  keyFilename: '/keyfile.json'
});

// The name of the audio file to transcribe
const fileName = this.state.audioPath;

// Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
const file = RNFS.readFile(fileName);
const audioBytes = file.toString('base64');

// The audio file's encoding, sample rate in hertz, and BCP-47 language code
const audio = {
  content: audioBytes
};

const config = {
  encoding: 'aac',
  sampleRateHertz: 32000,
  languageCode: 'vi-VN'
};

const request = {
  audio: audio,
  config: config
};

// Detects speech in the audio file
speechClient.recognize(request)
  .then((results) => {
    const transcription = results[0].results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
    this.setState({
      textReceived: transcription
    })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    this.setState({
      textReceived: 'Có lỗi Google Cloud STT, mời bạn request lại'
    })
  });
```

}

Error now: 'Unable to resolve module "child_process" from ...\google-auth-library\lib\auth\googleauth.js"

Comment: You don't know but did you try something ? If yes what did you try ?

Comment: I tried https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries for NodeJS. And now, I'm stuck at error while compiling: Unable to resolve module path ".../google-proto-files/index.js"

Comment: Would you mind trying [```react-native-android-voice```](https://github.com/JoaoCnh/react-native-android-voice) component?

Comment: tks milkersarac, I did your solution and it was fine to me now, but I really want to use Google Cloud Speech (because i stored audio files)

Comment: Can you show us the code where you had the error please ?

Comment: Here are my codes:

Comment: Hi! Were you ever able to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you can't use Google speech SDK on react native, it's a node library. So you need to first send your file to nodejs server then call the sdk methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-speech-to-text-android` to perform speech to text conversion.

```
import SpeechToText from 'react-native-google-speech-to-text';

const speechToTextHandler = async () => {
    let result = null;
        try {
            result = await SpeechToText.startSpeech('Try saying something', 'en_IN');
            console.log('Result: ', result);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error: ', error);
        }
}
```